# Excel Vlookup- adds up percentages with duplicate relationships

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, vlookup

Please refer to the image below. This data has one column called  entity ID and anther column, Parent entity and then the Percentage column for each relationship. Looking at the data I see there are some duplicate relationships with different percentages. For example, the first two rows highlighted in yellow (entity ID: 1 and Parent entity: 14805).

Is there a formula or vba I can do that adds the percentages for the duplicate relationships? We have one relationship that gives me a percentage equal to 1 and the other gives me a percentage of 2.965. I need to add these values up to give me the total percentage relationship of 3.965

Thanks in advance, let me know if I need to clarify anything.

[image: Formula SUMIF Check]

Comment: Do you want to sum them somewhere else, in the last entry – i.e. where it's now saying 2.965 – or do you want to merge them completely, removing the duplicate entry and adding them together?

Comment: If you are using `=VLOOKUP()`, as the title would suggest, in a cell to check the percentage of an ID, you've probably noticed that it will only return the first value. You can redeem this by using the `=SUMIF()` function instead, or if you want to compare both the ID and parent entity, use `=SUMIFS()`.

Comment: yes! that was the problem, I was using a vlookup and it was returning only the first value. I will try the sumifs function! thanks!

Comment: Quick tip then:         `=SUMIFS("percentagerange","IDrange","ID","parentrange","parent")`
Like `=SUMIFS($C$2:$C$100,$A$2:$A$100,A2,$B$2:$B$100,B2)` or similar. Ranges has to be the same length.

Comment: That's really helpful!! thanks!! so I used your formula and I see it correctly added the duplicate relationship percentages, but then now it is showing the duplicate sum's for example)  151 432 1 40 &  151 432 39 40, it is showing 40 twice because of the duplicate relationship in the other two columns. Any suggestions, I tried doing remove duplicates but didn't work.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you mean. I'm guessing you have the sumifs in a separate column, and you have the same ID returning the same percentage twice, since it's present twice in the table? 
Removing duplicates would not do a great work in this case.
If you could update with a picture including the sumifs and the problem that would be helpful for my thinking. But it's starting to sound like we need to add a macro soon.

Comment: yes that's exactly what's happening, I updated the image in the original question and I have your calculated formula in column " SUMIFCHECK." As you can see in yellow, it correctly added the duplicate percentage but now it shows up as a duplicate result.

Comment: Hmm yes. Is it a problem that you have duplicates in that row?
If the list is always sorted, so that the duplicates are always following each other, you could extend the function with a duplicate check using IF() & AND(). Suppose my function with A2 down and B2 down is right, it should look like (for when sumifs target is A2): `=IF(AND(A2=A3,B2=B3),"", -insert sumifs here-)`     

This checks is the row beneath it is a duplicate, and if so, displays an empty cell. Could that work?